# game.physics.arcade.overlap() is not working in phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I want to kill the bullet as it overlap the asteroid but its not working. Please have a look of my code. I looked in to the code many times but everything is looking right.  Also i want to perform collision over asteroid.

**game.js**

```js
var bullets;
var Game = {
    preload: function() {
        // Load the needed image for this(play) game screen.
        //load the menu screen
        this.load.image('menu', './assets/images/menu.png');

        // Here we load all the needed resources for the level.
        // background image screen
        this.load.image('playgame', './assets/images/back.png');

        // globe image screen
        // this.load.image('playgame', './assets/images/back.png');


        this.load.image('spaceship', './assets/images/spaceship.png');

        // Astroid image screen
        this.load.image('astroid1', 'assets/images/asteroid1.png');
        this.load.image('astroid2', 'assets/images/asteroid2.png');
        this.load.image('astroid3', 'assets/images/asteroid3.png');
        this.load.image('astroid4', 'assets/images/asteroid4.png');

        //Load the bullet
        this.load.image('bullet', 'assets/images/bullet.png');
    },
    create: function() {

        // By setting up global variables in the create function, we initialise them on game start.
        // We need them to be globally available so that the update function can alter them.

        //this will show the physics of background 
        game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

        //  The scrolling starfield background
        gameback = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'playgame');

        textStyle_Value = {
            font: "bold 20px Segoe UI",
            fill: defTextColor,
            align: "center"
        };
        textStyleAns = {
            font: "bold 22px 'Comic Sans MS', 'Comic Sans'",
            fill: ansTextColor,
            wordWrap: true,
            wordWrapWidth: 10,
            align: "center"
        };
        textStyleQues = {
            font: "bold 20px 'Comic Sans MS', 'Comic Sans'",
            fill: defTextColor,
            wordWrap: true,
            wordWrapWidth: 10,
            align: "center"
        };


        // Loading questionbar image
        this.questionbar();

        // csll fun. for place astroid
        this.astroid();
        // call fun. for Ans
        this.generateQues();
        this.generateAns();

        // Call fun. for ques
        this.comeQus();
        // Call fun. for ques
        this.comeAns();

        // Loading Diamond image
        this.diamond();
        // Start timer
        this.startTimer();
        // Set timer.
        this.setTimer();

        this.initLoader();


        bullets = game.add.group();
        bullets.enableBody = true;
        bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
        bullets.createMultiple(500, 'bullet', 150, false);
        // bullets.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
        // bullets.setAll('anchor.y', 0.5);
        bullets.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
        bullets.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);

        sprite = game.add.sprite(400, 530, 'spaceship');
        sprite.anchor.set(0.4);

        // Playing backgroud music
        fun_bckg = this.add.audio('fun_bckg', 1, true);
        fun_bckg.volume = 0.5;
        this.playFx('fun_bckg');

        // Bullet fire music
        fire_bullet = this.add.audio('fire_bullet', 1, true);
        fire_bullet.volume = 0.5;
        //this.playFx('fire_bullet');

    },
    astroid: function() {

        astroid1 = this.add.button(25, 100, 'astroid1', this.astroidClicked, this);
        astroid2 = this.add.button(250, 30, 'astroid2', this.astroidClicked, this);
        astroid3 = this.add.button(400, 40, 'astroid3', this.astroidClicked, this);
        astroid4 = this.add.button(570, 100, 'astroid4', this.astroidClicked, this);


    },

    fire: function() {


        this.playFx('fire_bullet');



        if (game.time.now > nextFire && bullets.countDead() > 0) {
            nextFire = game.time.now + fireRate;

            var bullet = bullets.getFirstDead();

            bullet.reset(sprite.x - 0, sprite.y - 140);

            game.physics.arcade.moveToPointer(bullet, 300);
        }

    }


}

function collisionHandler(bullets, astroid1) {
        alert("hello");

        //  When a bullet hits an alien we kill them both
        bullets.kill();
        astroid1.kill();


    }
    .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you should put the collision check into an update function like this:

```
update: function() {
   // check for collisions
   game.physics.arcade.collide(bullets, asteroid, this.bulletHitAsteroid, null, this);
}
```

and kill the sprites in that function (in this case the bulletHitAsteroid function).

```
bulletHitAsteroid(_bullets, _asteroid): function() {
   _bullet.kill();
   _asteroid.kill();
}
```

I hope this helps.